# writes to mysql slave server by mistake

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have mysql replication set up with one master and one slave. Due to a bug in the code, somewhere in the middle the entries started to get written on slave server and it was detected a few days later on.
Now I am thinking of how to switch it correctly without any hassle or minimal down time, what would be the best way to do this? Lets consider only one table...

> Solution 1

Simply start writing to master from now on after setting auto_increment to slave's last id. Wondering if it will be troublesome to keep master and slave out of sync.

> Solution 2

Clear all the data from master, stop the app from making any more entries refill the data using mysqldump and then switching the app back on with correct config.

```
stop slave
// load the dump
start slave
```

Will this stop master from re-attempting to write to slave the same data?

Any help appreciated. Any other solutions also welcomed.

Thanks
Sushil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the correct track with solution 2. Simply stopping the slave will not prevent the master from writing to it's binary log. So when you start the slave again it will just replicate all the SQL statements from the master.

However, you can use this to your advantage if you have included 'DROP TABLE' before each table creation. This will mean that you have the following:

1) Stop the app from making any more entries in the master table(s)

2) Dump data from slave (ensure that `mysqldump` includes 'DROP TABLE' before each table import - it should do as it is a default option of `mysqldump`)

3) Run dump against master

4) Check slave status using `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`. Once `Seconds_Behind_Master` reaches 0 then you are good to switch on the app again (make sure it is writing to the master!!)

Step 3 will drop and recreate the tables on the master using the data from the slave. This drop and recreate will be replicated on to the slave so you should end up with the two in sync and a correct master slave set up.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Tom! But what do _start/stop slave_ do - how can I make changes to master table that I do not want to run on slave as well?

Comment: Starting and stopping a slave in a replication environment will simply pause the slave. Once you switch it back on again it will start replicating at the master binlog position when you stopped it. Effectively it pauses replication. The whole point of my answer is that *do* want to make the changes to the slave. There is an assumption in my answer that all of the data that you want on your master is currently on your slave - hence the 'stop app, dump slave data, import dumped slave data to master and let changes replicate to slave' approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to reset the slave/master completely. If the data on the slave is correct reload the data from it and then export export a new dump from the master and import it to the slave, then execute a new "CHANGE MASTER TO..." command

I would recommend setting the "read_only" global variable on the slave.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_read-only